# Measure performance of web application?

Tags: performance, testing, playframework-2.1

What are the best tools to test the performance of a (not deployed) application using Play framework? Things like, how long takes a request to execute, with different parameters, simulating a lot of requests (stress test), etc.

I'm searching a while but the problem is that the keyword "performance", "benchmarks" etc. lead me to pages about the performance of Play framework.

I thought maybe [functional tests](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaFunctionalTest), could be used to measure performance (print difference between method start time and end...). But this doesn't look suitable for this kind of task.

I could just write a script, that triggers the requests, writes the timestamps to a log file... but maybe there's something finished, with extras, like e.g. charts, etc.

Any hint in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Iago](https://github.com/twitter/iago) is a load generation tool by Twitter written in Scala. Also, I've used the [Loader.io](http://loader.io/) addon on Heroku to do performance testing. Loader.io also has a non-heroku service that I have not used. Iago is probably your best bet for local testing of a non-public app.

Answer (score 1):

A good example is a project used by [Versal](https://versal.com/) to choose their Scala stack for production.

The project is [Scamper](https://github.com/Versal/scamper).